# pandas how to aggregate sum on a column depending on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation, pandas-groupby

I am trying to sum values in a column by `groupby` on values in a second column, but meanwhile also considering values on a 3rd column, the `df` is like,

```
id    memo    amount   
 1    pos     1.0 
 1    pos     2.0
 1    neg     3.0
 2    pos     4.0
 2    pos     5.0
 2    neg     6.0
 2    neg     7.0
```

I want to group by `id` and sum `amount`, but each group, if `memo` is `pos` it is positive and `neg` for negative, e.g. when `groupby` `1`, the total amount is 0, since `-1.0 - 2.0 + 3.0 = 0`.

If I do `df.groupby('id')['amount'].sum()`, it only considers `id` and `amount` column, I am wondering how to also take `memo` into account here.

so the result will look like,

```
id    memo    amount    total_amount   
 1    pos     1.0       0.0
 1    pos     2.0       0.0
 1    neg     3.0       0.0
 2    pos     4.0       -4.0
 2    pos     5.0       -4.0
 2    neg     6.0       -4.0
 2    neg     7.0       -4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the operation in two steps, you can achieve what you want through

```
df['temp'] = np.where(df.memo == 'pos', df.amount, -df.amount)
df['total_amount'] = df.groupby('id').temp.transform(sum)
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `numpy.where` on the first step

`df["temp"] = np.where(df["memo"]=="neg", -df["amount"], df["amount"])`

Comment: @user32185: Yep, does seem like that performs a bit better (and is a good deal more readable). Also beats the compromise `df.amount * np.where(df.memo == 'pos', 1, -1)` by a bit.

Comment: @fuglede what does the first step mean in original code

Comment: @daiyue: Apologies for removing that, making your comment a bit less clear. In the original code, `df.memo == 'pos'` would be a `Series` with values `True`/`False`, depending on the condition, `(df.memo == 'pos')*2` would be the same with values `2` and `0` respectively, and `(df.memo == 'pos')*2-1` would then be a `Series` with values `1` and `-1`. Multiplying this element-wise with `df.values` would produce your desired operation.

Answer (score 1):

Another fun way with mapping and multiplying i.e

```
df['new'] = (df.set_index('id')['memo'].map({'pos':1,'neg':-1})*df['amount'].values)\
            .groupby(level=0).transform(sum).values
```

Output :

```
   id memo  amount  new
0   1  pos     1.0  0.0
1   1  pos     2.0  0.0
2   1  neg     3.0  0.0
3   2  pos     4.0 -4.0
4   2  pos     5.0 -4.0
5   2  neg     6.0 -4.0
6   2  neg     7.0 -4.0
```